# Error using MVCContrib TestHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, mvccontrib-testhelper

While trying to implement the second answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887121/why-does-this-asp-net-mvc-unit-test-fail), I am receiving an error.

I have implemented the methods just as the post shows, and the first three work properly.  The fourth one (HomeController_Delete_Action_Handler_Should_Redirect_If_Model_Successfully_Delete) gives this error: Could not find a parameter named 'controller' in the result's Values collection.

If I change the code to:

```
actual 
    .AssertActionRedirect() 
    .ToAction("Index");
```

it works properly, but I don't like the "magic string" in there and prefer to use the lambda method that the other poster used.

My controller method looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(State model)
    {
        try
        {
            if( model == null )
            {
                return View( model );
            }

            _stateService.Delete( model );

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View( model );
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MVCContrib.TestHelper` expects you to specify the controller name when redirecting in the `Delete` action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Then you would be able to use the strongly typed assertion:

```
actual
    .AssertActionRedirect()
    .ToAction<HomeController>(c => c.Index());
```

Another alternative is to write your own `ToActionCustom` extension method:

```
public static class TestHelperExtensions
{
    public static RedirectToRouteResult ToActionCustom<TController>(
        this RedirectToRouteResult result, 
        Expression<Action<TController>> action
    ) where TController : IController
    {
        var body = (MethodCallExpression)action.Body;
        var name = body.Method.Name;
        return result.ToAction(name);
    }
}
```

which would allow you to leave the redirect as is:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

and test the result like this:

```
actual
    .AssertActionRedirect()
    .ToActionCustom<HomeController>(c => c.Index());
```

Comment: The custom extension method. I like that alternative and am using it. I don't like having to put the controller name in the RedirectToAction and this works perfectly.